# Playlist of favorites songs

Tags: music, ios, playlist, music.app

Is it possible to create a playlist on a iPhone with iOS 9 of all the favorite songs (by marking favorite with the heart icon)

Comment: With iTunes there may be a way to create a Smart Playlist. Have you tired that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create in iTunes a smart playlists of loved songs, and the playlist will be updated on the iPhone. If you mark a song as loved it will be added to the playlist without syncing.